# how to custom error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I am trying custom some error message

```
validates :username, :presence      => {:message => 'Email cannot be blank'}, 
                     :uniqueness    => {:message => 'Email was existed'}
```

but in the web page, it display like this:

```
Username Email cannot be blank
Username Invalid email format
Password Missing password
```

How can i get rid of the "Username" and "Password" in the very first word of each line??

(rails 3.0.7, ruby 1.9.2)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the code in the view that is displaying the errors with something like one of the examples below.

If you are using HAML:

```
- if @applicant.errors.any?
  %ul
  - @applicant.errors.each do |key, value|
    %li= value
```

If you are using ERB: (the rails default template engine)

```
<% if @applicant.errors.any? %>
  <ul>
    <% @applicant.errors.each do |key, value| %>
      <li><%= value %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Obviously there is a lot that can be done to style it, but I left that out for simplicity.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Same solution with more explanation: http://www.andrewtheis.net/blog/rails-3-and-form-errors.php